# c# Linq to read xml string

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EventNotificationAlert version="1.0" xmlns="urn:psialliance-org">
    <ipAddress>
        10.10.10.159
    </ipAddress>
    <peopleCounting>
        <enter>
            0
        </enter>
        <exit>
            0
        </exit>
        <pass>
            0
        </pass>
    </peopleCounting>
</EventNotificationAlert>
```

**Function :**

```
string s1 = reader.ReadToEnd();
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(s1);
XElement root = xmlDoc.Root;
var chartrate = from a in xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("/EventNotificationAlert/peopleCounting/")
    select new
    {
        _enter = a.Element("enter").Value,
        _exit = a.Element("exit").Value,
        _pass = a.Element("pass").Value
    };
```

**Question:**
Please assist on above linq function. It returns null. And please also add in how to print the result in foreach loop.

Comment: What part returns null?

Comment: var chartrate  on row 4

Comment: @LohZhiCheng it doesn't. It throws a different exception. If you check it you'll realise the XPath expression is invalid

Comment: I'd suggest not using XPath at all  in this case - just `XNamespace ns = "urn:psialliance-org"; var chartRate = xmlDoc.Root.Element(ns + "peopleCounting");` would be my first step. Note the use of the XML namespace there...

Comment: Hi Sir , how to continue from above code ? i mean variable chartRate how to select the next level element ?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for your help as well sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the source XML contains a namespace (`xmlns`) declaration, you also need to use that namespace when querying any element underneath it, like this:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(s1);
XNamespace ns = "urn:psialliance-org";

XElement peopleCounting = xmlDoc.Root.Element(ns + "peopleCounting");

string enter = peopleCounting.Element(ns + "enter").Value.Trim(); // Remove spaces from the value
string exit = peopleCounting.Element(ns + "exit").Value.Trim();
string pass = peopleCounting.Element(ns + "pass").Value.Trim();

Console.WriteLine(enter + " | " + exit + " | " + pass);
```

Or if you need to keep using the loop because there could be multiple `peopleCounting` nodes:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> allPeopleCounting = xmlDoc.Root.Elements(ns + "peopleCounting");

var result = from a in allPeopleCounting
             select new
             {
                 _enter = a.Element(ns + "enter").Value.Trim(),
                 _exit = a.Element(ns + "exit").Value.Trim(),
                 _pass = a.Element(ns + "pass").Value.Trim()
             };

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item._enter + " | " + item._exit + " | " + item._pass);
}
```